# what is my $JAVA_HOME path

Tags: amazon-ec2, java, amazon-web-services

Just launched an instance of EC2  and I tried doing:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
```

it gives me back:

```
 $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.1) (amazon-44.1.9.1.21.amzn1-i386)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 19.0-b06, mixed mode)
```

so I can see that it is installed there. I opened up my bash profile however I don't see what my JAVA_HOME path is? How do I get this? THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

echo $JAVA_HOME

or

env | grep JAVA

Answer (score 0):

Your java path is displayed from /etc/profile.d/aws-apitools-common.sh

If you want to install your own jdk use the following documentation:

https://evandhoffman.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/installing-sun-oracle-jdk-1-5-on-an-ec2-instance/